# Fetch albums from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have tried to fetch all album IDs from facebook using the following code.
But only first 25 albums were returned. Did I miss something?

```
response = facebook.request("me/albums");
json = Util.parseJson(response);
albums = json.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i =0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject album = albums.getJSONObject(i);
    String album_name = album.getString("name");
    String album_id = album.getString("id");
}
```

Comment: +1 for you.. Hey can u please post the full source code of how to get the Album's data from Facebook Hackbook? I want to upload photos into particular album. I found nothing can u plz post your whole code so that I can get idea of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But only first 25 albums were returned. Did I miss something?

Yes – that 25 is the default `limit` parameter value for requests like this.

Either use the paging links to retrieve the next 25 and so on, or set a higher limit yourself.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/

Comment: Thx a lot, I solved this issue by using "paging" and "next" keyword to get next page URI.

Answer (score 0):

I use following ways to get the rest of album list.

```
next_page_URL = null; 
next = json.getJSONObject("paging"); 
next_page_URL = next.getString("next"); 
response = facebook.request("me/albums&"+next_page_URL);
```